# In R, how do delete rows with duplicated (date) value in one column based on missing (NA) values in another

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, missing-data

I can't figure our how to delete rows with duplicated value of the column dates and, choose to delete the row which has missing value (NA) of inst, grouped by id.

A minimal working example of my data is :

```
id <- c("N101", "N102", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N104", "N105", "N107", "N107", "N108", "N109", "N110", "N111", "N112", "N113", "N114", "N115", "N116", "N116")
inst <- c("angers", "strasbourg",  NA, "angers", "montpellier", NA,            "rouen", "limoges", NA, "brest", "stanne", "aphp_psl", "stanne",      "strasbourg",  "clairval", "stanne", "stanne", "caen", NA, "brest")
dates <- c("2008-07-13", "2008-02-13", "2008-05-13", "2008-05-13", "2010-12-14", "2011-12-19", "2013-11-12", "2014-01-31", "2008-06-13", "2009-06-09", "2009-03-10", "2008-12-10", "2010-04-15", "2008-01-13", "2017-03-13", "2014-05-14", "2012-05-15", "2009-10-22", "2010-10-18", "2011-05-03")
df1 <- data.frame (id, inst, dates)

> df1
     id        inst      dates
1  N101      angers 2008-07-13
2  N102  strasbourg 2008-02-13
3  N103        <NA> 2008-05-13
4  N103      angers 2008-05-13
5  N103 montpellier 2010-12-14
6  N103        <NA> 2011-12-19
7  N104       rouen 2013-11-12
8  N105     limoges 2014-01-31
9  N107        <NA> 2008-06-13
10 N107       brest 2009-06-09
11 N108      stanne 2009-03-10
12 N109    aphp_psl 2008-12-10
13 N110      stanne 2010-04-15
14 N111  strasbourg 2008-01-13
15 N112    clairval 2017-03-13
16 N113      stanne 2014-05-14
17 N114      stanne 2012-05-15
18 N115        caen 2009-10-22
19 N116        <NA> 2010-10-18
20 N116       brest 2011-05-03
```

In the MWE above, the row 3
`3  N103        <NA> 2008-05-13`
should be deleted and produce the df:

```
id <- c("N101", "N102", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N104", "N105", "N107", "N107", "N108", "N109", "N110", "N111", "N112", "N113", "N114", "N115", "N116", "N116")
inst <- c("angers", "strasbourg", "angers", "montpellier", NA,            "rouen", "limoges", NA, "brest", "stanne", "aphp_psl", "stanne",      "strasbourg",  "clairval", "stanne", "stanne", "caen", NA, "brest")
dates <- c("2008-07-13", "2008-02-13", "2008-05-13", "2010-12-14", "2011-12-19", "2013-11-12", "2014-01-31", "2008-06-13", "2009-06-09", "2009-03-10", "2008-12-10", "2010-04-15", "2008-01-13", "2017-03-13", "2014-05-14", "2012-05-15", "2009-10-22", "2010-10-18", "2011-05-03")
df2 <- data.frame (id, inst, dates)

> df2
     id        inst      dates
1  N101      angers 2008-07-13
2  N102  strasbourg 2008-02-13
3  N103      angers 2008-05-13
4  N103 montpellier 2010-12-14
5  N103        <NA> 2011-12-19
6  N104       rouen 2013-11-12
7  N105     limoges 2014-01-31
8  N107        <NA> 2008-06-13
9  N107       brest 2009-06-09
10 N108      stanne 2009-03-10
11 N109    aphp_psl 2008-12-10
12 N110      stanne 2010-04-15
13 N111  strasbourg 2008-01-13
14 N112    clairval 2017-03-13
15 N113      stanne 2014-05-14
16 N114      stanne 2012-05-15
17 N115        caen 2009-10-22
18 N116        <NA> 2010-10-18
19 N116       brest 2011-05-03
```

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you only want to delete rows with `NA` if the date is duplicated?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I would like to do.

Comment: Could you suggest me a solution with dplyr ?

Answer (score 4):

With some ordering so that NAs come last and then checking for duplication, to avoid the group operation:

```
o <- order(df1$id, df1$dates, is.na(df1$inst))
df1[o,][!duplicated(df1[o, c("id","dates")]),]
#     id        inst      dates
#1  N101      angers 2008-07-13
#2  N102  strasbourg 2008-02-13
#4  N103      angers 2008-05-13
#5  N103 montpellier 2010-12-14
#6  N103        <NA> 2011-12-19
#7  N104       rouen 2013-11-12
#8  N105     limoges 2014-01-31
#9  N107        <NA> 2008-06-13
#10 N107       brest 2009-06-09
#11 N108      stanne 2009-03-10
#12 N109    aphp_psl 2008-12-10
#13 N110      stanne 2010-04-15
#14 N111  strasbourg 2008-01-13
#15 N112    clairval 2017-03-13
#16 N113      stanne 2014-05-14
#17 N114      stanne 2012-05-15
#18 N115        caen 2009-10-22
#19 N116        <NA> 2010-10-18
#20 N116       brest 2011-05-03
```

If *dplyr* is a pre-requisite, then you can adapt it:

```
df1 %>%
    arrange(id, dates, is.na(inst)) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(select(., id, dates)))
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(id, dates) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(inst) & n() > 1L))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 3
# Groups:   id, dates [19]
   id    inst        dates     
   <fct> <fct>       <fct>     
 1 N101  angers      2008-07-13
 2 N102  strasbourg  2008-02-13
 3 N103  angers      2008-05-13
 4 N103  montpellier 2010-12-14
 5 N103  NA          2011-12-19
 6 N104  rouen       2013-11-12
 7 N105  limoges     2014-01-31
 8 N107  NA          2008-06-13
 9 N107  brest       2009-06-09
10 N108  stanne      2009-03-10
11 N109  aphp_psl    2008-12-10
12 N110  stanne      2010-04-15
13 N111  strasbourg  2008-01-13
14 N112  clairval    2017-03-13
15 N113  stanne      2014-05-14
16 N114  stanne      2012-05-15
17 N115  caen        2009-10-22
18 N116  NA          2010-10-18
19 N116  brest       2011-05-03
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works help on my > 2000 rows database.